# How to set up apache running on separate system OL7 to present trac wiki project

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, python, svn, trac

I need to somehow set up apache to present a content from tracd running on separate server.

I used following config definition:

```
# LB VIP1 - TRAC definition <VirtualHost "IP":8090>
#        ServerName tracwiki.com
        ServerAlias "IP of loadbalancer"
#        ServerPath "/project/"
DocumentRoot "/pkg/moip/data/apache/docs"   <Directory "/pkg/moip/data/apache/docs">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require method GET HEAD POST   
</Directory>   RewriteRule ^/project_name/(.*) http://"IP of Application server":8000/project/$1 [L,P]
    LogLevel warn core:info
    ErrorLog /pkg/moip/logs/apache/error_TRAC.log
    CustomLog /pkg/moip/logs/apache/access_TRAC.log common
    Redirect /project          https://tracwiki.com/project
#    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /project         http://"IP of Application server":8000/project
    ProxyPassReverse /project  http://"IP of Application server":8000/project  
    Include /pkg/moip/apps/apache/conf/extra/limits.conf </VirtualHost>*
```

Unfortunately I still get a same message "content not found". Firewall between servers is opened via port 8000 (in direction web server to application server). Tracdeamon is running well on application server.

```
Package Version: 
Trac 1.2.3,
Genshi 0.7.1 (with speedups),
pysqlite 2.8.3,
Python 2.7.5 (default, Jul 3 2018, 06:28:28) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28.0.1)],
setuptools 0.9.8,
SQLite 3.7.17,
Subversion 1.7.14 (r1542130)
```

I also installed "flup" to use ajp protocols instead of http, but unfortunately I couldn't manage to properly start a gateway:

```
[trac-scripts]$ Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/lcuser/trac-scripts/ajp_to_wsgi_gateway", line 36, in <module>
        from flup.server.ajp import WSGIServer   File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/flup/server/ajp.py", line 91, in <module>   File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/flup/server/ajp_base.py", line 42, in <module> ImportError: No module named _thread
```

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue. As I expected I had a problem in my VirtualHost definition.
I needed only add specific "rewrite rule" in my existing definition:

```
RewriteRule ^/project_name(.*) http://"IP of Application server1":8000/project_name$1 [L,P]
```

Correctly should be like this:

```
<VirtualHost "IP":8090>
    ServerName tracwiki.com
    ServerAlias "IP of loadbalancer"

DocumentRoot "/pkg/moip/data/apache/docs"   
<Directory "/pkg/moip/data/apache/docs">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require method GET HEAD POST   
</Directory>

#Prevent TRACK/TRACE requests   
    RewriteEngine on   
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)   
    RewriteRule .* - [F]
    RewriteRule [^a-zA-Z0-9|;|/|\ |\?|:|Q|&|=|\+|\$|,|\-|_|\.|\!|~|\*|\(|\)] - [F]      
    RewriteRule ^/project_name(.*) http://"IP of Application server1":8000/project_name$1 [L,P]

LogLevel warn core:info   ErrorLog /pkg/moip/logs/apache/error.log   
CustomLog /pkg/moip/logs/apache/access.log common

<IfModule mod_proxy_balancer.c>
    Header add Set-Cookie "ROUTEID=.%{BALANCER_WORKER_ROUTE}e; path=/" env=BALANCER_ROUTE_CHANGED  
<Proxy balancer://cluster>
    BalancerMember http://"IP of Application server2":21180 route=App_1 keepalive=on
    BalancerMember http://"IP of Application server3":21180 route=App_2 keepalive=on

    ProxySet stickysession=ROUTEID lbmethod=byrequests  
</Proxy>  
    ProxyPass / balancer://cluster/  
    ProxyPassReverse / balancer://cluster/ 
</IfModule>
Include /pkg/moip/pepsig/apps/apache/conf/extra/limits.conf </VirtualHost>*
```

"Server1" -- used exclusively for TRAC WIKI purposes

"Server2" + "Server3" -- used only for JBOSS instances (application purposes).